# Web Developer Console: "Slow network is detected." with fonts

Tags: css, javascript

I am new to coding and just started working on a website. The issue that I am having is the extreme lag time. The site that I am using is in wordpress with a custom theme. Every plugin has been updated, even the theme. I checked the Developer Tools in the browser and this came up in the console.

Can anyone explain to me what this means, please?

[image]

Comment: Check the same page with all browser extensions turned off. Actually, this is not a WordPress-related question.

Comment: Also, check if any of the plugins or theme uses `font-display:auto;` CSS property.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the network is slow. The browser is smart enough to detect that the network is slow based on the time it takes to load your webpage. It is replacing the web font with a local fallback. The text rendered with a web font will not be visible until the font is downloaded.

You can fix this issue by following these steps:

1. Update your browser to the latest version
2. Disable AdBlock Plus extension for Google chrome

Also, follow the instructions provided by @Max Yudin in the comments.